# Hiding Web browser navigation while running jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written one java file through Eclipse IDE and export that program into executable jar file. Now when i double click on jar file, application is running in IE and it is doing whatever code in the code. But that UI navigation of my code is happening and visible to the user of jar file. How can i hide that ?

**My java code written using selenium.**

My jar file will do following things
1. code will prompt for input 
2. Launch the URL 
3. entering username and pwd
4. Using the input which was asked at setp 1, application will do some functions

i want to hide launchng url, functions that are doing in code. User(who is using this jar ) want to see only prompt and result . Is this possible to hide application navigation . Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use [Desktops](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) from the MS SysInternals package. You can spawn your Chrome process directly from the "hidden" desktop and keep it working there (I have not personally tested this).

## Other option...

You could try spawning Chrome as a child process using something like Node.js and piping the output back to the terminal.

Using Linux is much easier or if you are running the test in Jenkins you can run it with Xvfb